# How can i split my data in pandas into specified buckets e.g. 40-40-20?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, binning

All,

i am trying to split my data into 3 buckets that is 40%, 40% and 20%. How can i do this using pandas?
e.g. so you get the bottom lowest 40%, middle 40% and top 20% :

```
pd.cut(df['count'], 5,labels = ['1','2','3','4','5'],retbins=True)
```

above splits into 5 quintiles, but i would like to 40:40:20 percentiles defined.

any ideas?

Comment: pd.qcut(df['count'], 5, labels = ['4','8','10'],retbins=True) <--- how does this work the numer of labels do not equal number of segments??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path. From the wording in your question I'm not sure if you want to bin the data based on the range of possible values or the actual distribution of values. I'll show both.

Use pd.cut() for binning data based on the range of possible values.
Use pd.qcut() for binning data based on the actual distribution of values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
labels = ['Bottom 40%', 'Middle 40%', 'Top 20%']

# bin data based on range of possible values
df['possible'] = pd.cut(df['count'], [0, 40, 80, 100], labels=labels)

# bin data based on distribution of values
df['distribution'] = pd.qcut(df['count'], [0., .4, .8, 1.], labels=labels)

top20possible = df.loc[df['possible'] == 'Top 20%']
top20distribution = df.loc[df['distribution'] == 'Top 20%']
```

Comment: i want to bin based on distrubution i.e. 20th percentile so i am assuming from your answer it is the qcut

Comment: @Maths12 Yes, you are correct! Use qcut to bin by the actual distribution. You can feed it whatever bin edges you want, or divide it evenly by using a single scalar vs. array.

Comment: @Maths12 can you please accept this answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) instead:

```py
df["quantile"] = pd.qcut(df["count"], q=[0, 0.4, 0.8, 1],
                         labels=["lowest", "middle", "top"])
```

```
>>> df.sort_values("count")

    count quantile
4       5   lowest
7       7   lowest
6       9   lowest
15      9   lowest
5      17   lowest
1      19   lowest
9      22   lowest
2      25   lowest
16     25   lowest
12     29   middle
19     31   middle
18     32   middle
0      32   middle
10     36   middle
14     38   middle
3      39   middle
8      44      top
11     47      top
17     47      top
13     48      top
```

To get the bins:

```
df["quantile"], bins = pd.qcut(df["count"], q=[0, 0.4, 0.8, 1],
                               labels=["lowest", "middle", "top"],
                               retbins=True)
```

Comment: how can i alo return the bins?

Comment: IIRC should be the same as `cut`: `retbins=True` no?

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (10000)

Comment: If you want to have an accuracy answer to your post, take care to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and obviously read the documentation... Thanks.